# Strting for loop tag inside if else tag raise error

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, jinja2

In jinja template there is a for loop in my script, with a start tag `{% for each in list_one %}` and end tag `{% endfor %}`.

I want to set 2 conditions for choosing the starting tag of for loop to work. Something like this:

```
{% if name %}
    {% for each in list_one %}
{% else %}
    {% for each in list_two %}
        {{ each }}
{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

The error I face with is:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError:Encountered unknown tag 'endif'.
>   You probably made a nesting mistake. Jinja is expecting this tag, but
>   currently looking for 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that
>   needs to be closed is 'for'.

Comment: starting a `for` in an if or else part means you have to end it in that part too. Right now you are starting `for` in if and in else, and end it after endif. Think of them as HTML tags, they go in pairs and need to be nested correctly

Comment: This won't work for you. You has to close `for` loop before `if` close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to close the `for` loop before the `if` clause. In order to decide which list to iterate upon, you can do this instead:

```
{% if name %}
    {% set desired_list = list_one %}
{% else %}
    {% set desired_list = list_two %}
{% endif %}
{% for each in desired_list %}
    {{ each }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I agree, this is the way to do it... (up voting)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `for` loop both in `if` and `else` blocks. But you missed to close `for` loop before closing your `if` and `else` blocks.

The correct code is like:

```
{% if name %}
    {% for each in list_one %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% for each in list_two %}
        {{ each }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```